# Choosing from a range of numbers with normal distribution

Tags: matlab, statistics, octave, normal-distribution

I need to choose one pixel from a range of, for example, 0 to 1920 pixels with the normal distribution, but I have no idea how to do this in MatLab. I know that I can use `normrnd()` to retrieve a random value given `mu` and `sigma`, but how do I apply this to my situation?

`mu` might be at 500 pixels and `sigma` 100 pixels, for example.

My current approach is this

```
function xpos = apply_normal_distribution(mu, sigma, min_xpos=1, max_xpos=1920)
    % Applies normal distribution with median mu and standard deviation sigma
    % xpos will always be: min <= xpos <= max
    xpos = ceil(normrnd(mu, sigma));
    if xpos > max_xpos
        xpos = max_xpos;
    elseif xpos < min_xpos
        xpos = min_xpos;
    endif
end
```

So I'm just using `normrnd` and cutting off if the value is higher or lower than my bounds. Don't know how good this is, but it works.

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing, because I don't know how to start. Only tried the `normrnd()` function, but couldn't figure out how to apply it here. My knowledge in statistics is not the best, unfortunately.

Comment: Your probably not going to get much help here.  Typically a question contains a specific item, with the users code ( effort ) as part of the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks - I think I figured it out by myself now anyway. Just needed to understand the concept a bit better.

Comment: Is the distribution related to the position of pixels or related to the value of pixels?

Comment: I just want to select one single pixel on my monitor, so it's related to the position.

Comment: Is your monitor 1920*1920 ?

Comment: No, it's not. The vertical position does not matter, I only need to choose a x-coordinate. If that's why you asked.

Comment: Sorry, should have added that, it was obvious to me.

Comment: _0 to 1920 pixels with the normal distribution_ That's impossible. A normal distribution is unbounded

Comment: I think cutting off is not correct.Higher or lower values should be dropped.

Comment: I know that it's actually unbounded, but I don't know how to handle this case correctly, either.

Comment: Maybe it would be an option to just try it again if the result is invalid, but then I would actually do the same because I'm just filtering out invalid results.

Comment: Nope, setting the invalid result to min and max is different from dropping it . If you draw histogram of your generated data there will be 2 peaks in 0 and 1920.

Comment: Yeah, okay, that's right. So just choosing again is the better option?

Comment: Yes use a loop to choose random numbers until you get the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you bound a normal distribution (or filter its results in any other way) it is not a normal distribution anymore. However, there exists a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) which is the closest thing to what you are looking for. It has it's own set of properties which are similar to a normal distribution *if* the bounds are far away from the mean and you have a low variance. With Matlab you can make that with:

```
mu = 500;
sigma = 100;
%truncate at 0 and 1920
pd = truncate(makedist('Normal',mu,sigma),0,1920);
% take some (10) samples
samples = random(pd,10,1);
```

Building it from scratch for Octave:

Your self-made proposal has the problem that if a realisation is outside the bound, you set the value to the bound value. Therefore the bound value will be overly proportional chosen. A less dirty way is instead to just draw a fresh value. I don't have a working Octave, but something like this should do it:

```
function xpos = apply_normal_distribution(mu, sigma, min_xpos=1, max_xpos=1920)
    % new realisations are drawn as long as they are outside the bounds.
    while xpos<min_xpos | xpos>max_xpos 
            xpos = ceil(normrnd(mu, sigma));
    end
end
```

Just as a warning: If it is unlikely that a realisation will be within the bounds then this may run for a very long time...

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I'm actually working with Octave, and it seems `makedist` is not implemented here yet.

Comment: @herhuf So in addition to/Instead of `matlab` tag you should use `octave` in your question.

Comment: Thats what I just did, too. Still - thank you! This does it for me.